# More pythonic way to do this (string splitting)?

Tags: python

`d` is a string list where each item is composed of two parts (connected by a dot). I want to extract the parts before and after the dot for each string item.

Here is how I did it.

```
d = ['a1.b1', 'a2.b2', 'a3.b3']
b = [c.split('.')[0] for c in d]
a = [c.split('.')[1] for c in d]
```

But I guess there is some more pythonic way?

Comment: very similar except simpler than mine

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `zip()` function:

```
>>> a,b = zip(*[i.split('.') for i in d])
>>> a
('a1', 'a2', 'a3')
>>> b
('b1', 'b2', 'b3')
```

Comment: You don't need to use a list comp `zip(*(i.split('.') for i in d))`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I think using list comprehension has more performance than generator expression in terms of execution time. Because by using generator expression python will does an extra jobs again (calling the generator function and using `iter` and `next` methods ), ;-) . read my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33634130/why-is-any-running-slower-than-using-loops/33634284

Comment: If you have large amounts of data you are potentially creating multiple copies which may cause issue

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yep, in terms of memory use actually a generator expression would performs so much better.

Comment: Watch out, though; if `d` is empty, the assignment will fail due to not enough values to unpack!

Comment: @user2357112 Yes but it seems that `d` is not variable.